# GPU is not used even after specifying gpu_layers in ctransformers

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, llama, llama-cpp-python

I have installed ctransformers using -

```
pip install ctransformers[cuda]
```

I am trying following piece of code -

```
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
config = {'max_new_tokens': 512, 'repetition_penalty': 1.1, 'context_length': 8000, 'temperature':0, 'gpu_layers':50}
llm = CTransformers(model = "./codellama-7b.Q4_0.gguf", model_type = "llama", gpu_layers=50, config=config)
```

Here gpu_layers parameter is specified still gpu is not being used and complete load is on cpu.
Can someone please point out if there is any step missing.

Comment: could you please share console details, the messages you see on console once you run the program